# Cup product for relative cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider $U,V\subseteq X$ open and let $p_U:X\to (X,U)$ and $p_V:X\to (X,V)$ and $p_{U\cup V}:X\to (X,U\cup V)$ be the projections. Furthermore, let $\alpha\in H^n(X,U)$ and $\beta\in H^m(X,V)$. Then $\alpha\smile\beta\in H^{n+m}(X,U\cup V)$. Is it always true that
$$p_{U\cup V}^*(\alpha\smile \beta) = p_U^*\alpha\smile p_V^*\beta~?$$
Is the condition that $U,V\subseteq X$ have to be open necessary?